# How do I recalculate the positions of elements painted on a JPanel?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel, swingworker

I'm trying to make a kind of AsteroidFighter game in Java.

I create a JPanel and paint several .png-files on the Panel, my spaceship, some obstacles like asteroids and collectables and of course the projectiles my spaceship is shooting. All of these objects are moving.
Both the obstacles and the projectiles are saved in ArrayLists.

I am using a swing-timer to repaint my JPanel every 25 ms.

As far as I know, i should use the paintComponent method from my JPanel only for drawing/painting my .png-files and NOT for recalculating the positions of my objects and detecting collisions between my projectiles, obstacles und my spaceship.

My question is:

How/where should i recalculate positions and detect collisions?

- Should I use an extra Thread/Runnable, which will, as far as I know, 
  interfere with the Event Dispatch Thread?
- Should I use a Swingworker, which is executed not only once but in an endless loop?
- Or should I use something else i did not think about so far?

Thank You in advance for some suggestions, either where and what to read/recherche or what to use.

Cheers, max

Comment: How long does it take to calculate? It doesn't seems to take too long. The overheads of Threads and SwingWorker might even take longer time IMO.

Comment: You are right. My recalculations take at the moment, according to the time i get from System.currentTimeMillis(), only 2 - 23 ms. Thank You so far!